My image Export fbx file not showing
I have added an image doing ⇧ Shift + A, then Image > Mesh Plane.  Then hit Z key, material preview, but when I go to Export FBX, my file is missing.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong
My steps that a teacher gave me in zoom class: ⇧ Shift + A > Image > Mesh Plane, select file png, then had to save and include _BR.png.
Did step to move image, then enlarge image, click File > Export > FBX, not seeing my file. I don't think its the same problem.


An image on a plane counts as a material in Blender. See FBX export why there are no materials or textures.

This question is similar to: FBX export why there are no materials or textures?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is the problem here? You don't see a file you haven't exported yet?
